# Is there Emacs version of VimGolf?

Tags: emacs

Does anyone know Emacs version of VimGolf? I can't find it. But there should be any site. I want to know how others use Emacs and learn more productive way. Thanks.

Comment: Following this emacs channel on SO is a very good way to learn a lot from others !

Comment: Don't close this, people. Questions about Emacs (and questions about programming tools in general) are explicitly *on topic*.

Answer (score 3):

Is [this](https://github.com/igrigorik/vimgolf/blob/master/emacs/vimgolf.el) what you're looking for?

Comment: Is it possible to view others answer of Emacs keystroke from this?

Answer (score 2):

Tim Visher has a series of [videos on the subject](http://vimeo.com/timvisher/videos/page:1/sort%3anewest). I guess this is most comprehensive resource you can find.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Irreal](http://irreal.org/blog/) blog, you'll find many posts related to [vimgolf in emacs](http://irreal.org/blog/?s=vimgolf), where readers post and compare their solutions.